# Bibliography is not printed in pdf

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have been using Texstudio, Jabref and "MiKTeX 2.9" for my research work since 1917. There was absoluely no problem in compiling ".tex" file into ".pdf". In fact, the latest ".pdf" file created on **23 Aug. 2023** contains all cited references, even though *the names of ".tex" and ".bib" files were not the same*. However, recently bibliography does not appear in compiled ".pdf" with **the same** ".tex" file! All attempts were failed! I have tried all given answers and commonds with no result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We don't know what exactly are "all given answers" that you tried. Please tell us exactly what you did. Otherwise it is hard to help you. Did you run BibTeX or biber? Do you get some warnings or errors?

Comment: 1) Yes I got errors, but exactly misleading ones.
2) Two years ago, I had no problem with compiling!
3) I have run both BibTeX and biber with no result.
4) I have followed all comments by contributors.
But I found an unusual way to solve my problem; I used a formerly archieved “.bbl” file and ran BibTeX. With such a trick “Pdf” showed all hyperlinked references. I cannot understand why TeXStudio cannot translate “.bib” file to “.bbl” file as before. Maybe, one needs a special software in order to convert “.bib” file into “.bbl”.